# Sharing data between stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure called `dbo.Match`.
It looks like this :

```sql
CREATE Procedure [dbo].[MATCH]
@parameterFromUser  nvarchar(30),
@checkbool int
As 
Begin
--SOME CODE
select RowId, 
       PercentMatch 
from @Matches
End
```

This procedure is being called from another stored procedure :

```sql
CREATE Procedure MatchMotherFirstName 
@MotherFN nvarchar(20) , @checkbool int
As begin
 SELECT @constVal = FunctionWeight 
 FROM   dbo.FunctionWeights 
 WHERE  FunctionWeights.FunctionId = 20;
 /*
    Some code to execute `dbo.Match` procedure in above procedure called `MatchMotherFirstName` , retrieve `RowNumber` and `PercentMatch`,
    Insert into #Temp in their respective fields , and calculate `PercentMatch * constVal`,
    and insert in corresponding column called `percentage` in `#Temp`
 */
End
```

I need to execute `dbo.Match` stored procedure in above procedure, retrieve `RowID` and PecrntMatch value, `@constval` value we have above, multiply `@constVal` and `percentmatch` and store it in `Percentage` column of `#Temp` and insert results from `dbo.Match procedure` in a temporary table. `dbo.Match` returns only `RowId` and `PercentMatch`.

Structure of Temporary table:

```
create table #Temp
(
Rownumber int not null,
ValFromUser nvarchar(30),
ColumnName nvarchar(30),
ValFromFunc decimal(18, 4),
FuncWeight decimal(18, 4),    -- @constVal here
Percentage decimal(18, 4) not null, -- calculated value here i.e (FuncWeight * ValFromFunc)

);
```

In `#Temp`, I need to insert the value of `@constVal` as well as calculate a column and insert i.e `PercentMatch * contVal` for rows inserted in this execution call only.
How can I do this in above procedure in most efficient way ?

***Edit :*** For purpose of clarity , here is what I was doing if `dbo.Match` was a function and not a procedure:

```
  if @MotherFN is not null 
  begin

    SELECT @constVal = FunctionWeight 
    FROM   dbo.FunctionWeights 
    WHERE  FunctionWeights.FunctionId = 20;
    INSERT INTO #Temp2                   
(RowNumber,ValFromUser,ColumnName,ValFromFunc,FuncWeight,percentage)
  SELECT RowId, 
         @MotherFN  ,
        'mothersfirstname'
        ,PercentMatch,
         @constVal,
         PercentMatch * @constVal
  FROM   dbo.MatchMatch(@MotherFN, 0)

    end
```

Like I can retrieve value of `Percentmatch`, `@constval` and multiply them both to insert in #Temp , how I may do this while I execute the `dbo.Match` procedure instead of calling `dbo.Match` function ?

Comment: This is old, but it's a very good article on the subject: [How to Share Data between Stored Procedures](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html) - gives you lots of choices, depending on your needs.

Comment: I read that `@MotherFN` parameter as "mother-effin"

Comment: @JoeEnos: Thank you for the link but this is exactly what I read before posting here. Does not answer how I may insert calculated valued based on column values returned from execution of stored procedure.

Comment: Why exactly has it been downvoted ? I actually thought it may add value as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options, ranging from incredibly easy to overly complicated. The easiest (and most efficient) ways of doing what you describe are:

1. Don't do it: just include that calculation in the query. Why does it need to be in the table definition?
2. Add a computed column the temp table when it is created. This requires that you also include a field to store the "Constant Value" so that it can be referenced by the computed column. If the calculation is somewhat expensive and/or there will be lots of rows and frequently selected from (and possibly used in WHERE and/or ORDER BY clauses), then you can make the computed column `PERSISTED` so that it is calculated upon `INSERT` and any `UPDATE` that updates the fields referenced in the computed column.
3. Add a computed column the temp table after the table has been created. This allows for embedding the "Constant Value" into the computed column so that there is no need for a `[ConstantValue]` column. If the calculation is somewhat expensive and/or there will be lots of rows and frequently selected from (and possibly used in WHERE and/or ORDER BY clauses), then you can make the computed column `PERSISTED` so that it is calculated upon `INSERT` and any `UPDATE` that updates the fields referenced in the computed column.

   P.S. Just in case you find yourself asking "why not just create the temp table dynamically in one step instead of two steps?": a local temporary table created in Dynamic SQL will cease to exist after the `EXEC` of that Dynamic SQL. A global temp table will survive the execution of the Dynamic SQL, but then the table name is shared across all sessions so another session executing this code at the same time would error on the name conflict. In that case you would need to generate a GUID via `NEWID()` to use as the global temp table name and concatenate that value as well into the Dynamic SQL, but then you are stuck being required to use Dynamic SQL for all references to the global temp table (including for the `INSERT...EXEC`) and that is just more work for no benefit.

**Test Setup**

```sql
IF (OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#InnerProc') IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
  DROP PROCEDURE #InnerProc;
END;
GO

IF (OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#TempResults1') IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
  DROP TABLE #TempResults1;
END;
IF (OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#TempResults2') IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
  DROP TABLE #TempResults2;
END;
IF (OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#TempResults3') IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
  DROP TABLE #TempResults3;
END;
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE #InnerProc
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;

  SELECT TOP 20 so.[object_id], so.[modify_date]
  FROM   [master].[sys].[objects] so
  ORDER BY so.[modify_date] DESC;
GO
```

**Option 1**

```sql
CREATE TABLE #TempResults1
(
  [ObjectId] INT NOT NULL,
  [ModifyDate] DATETIME NOT NULL
);

DECLARE @ConstantValue1 INT;
SET @ConstantValue1 = 13;

INSERT INTO #TempResults1 ([ObjectId], [ModifyDate])
  EXEC #InnerProc;

SELECT 1 AS [Test], *, DATEADD(DAY, @ConstantValue1, [ModifyDate]) AS [SomeCalculation]
FROM #TempResults1;
```

**Option 2**

```sql
CREATE TABLE #TempResults2
(
  [ObjectId] INT NOT NULL,
  [ModifyDate] DATETIME NOT NULL,
  [ConstantValue] INT NULL, -- will be added via UPDATE
  [SomeCalculation] AS (DATEADD(DAY, [ConstantValue], [ModifyDate])) -- PERSISTED ??
);

INSERT INTO #TempResults2 ([ObjectId], [ModifyDate])
  EXEC #InnerProc;

SELECT 2 AS [Test], * FROM #TempResults2;

UPDATE #TempResults2
SET    [ConstantValue] = 13;

SELECT 2 AS [Test], * FROM #TempResults2;
```

**Option 3**

```sql
DECLARE @ConstantValue3 INT;
SET @ConstantValue3 = 13;

CREATE TABLE #TempResults3
(
  [ObjectId] INT NOT NULL,
  [ModifyDate] DATETIME NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO #TempResults3 ([ObjectId], [ModifyDate])
  EXEC #InnerProc;

SELECT 3 AS [Test], * FROM #TempResults3;

-- The next 3 lines could be done just after the CREATE TABLE and before the INSERT,
-- but doing it now allows for seeing the "before" and "after" with the data.
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @SQL = N'ALTER TABLE #TempResults3 ADD [SomeCalculation] AS (DATEADD(DAY, '
           + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), @ConstantValue3) + N', [ModifyDate])); --PERSISTED';
EXEC (@SQL);

SELECT 3 AS [Test], * FROM #TempResults3;
```

Comment: I think I created some serious misunderstanding in what I was trying to ask by not showing Temporary table. Updated the question with it. Could you please have a look ?

Comment: As you suggested in your second point, I already do have a field there, I just do not know how to insert calculated value in the table while I retrieve values from execution of procedure.

Comment: @Simran What you are asking for is still not clear. Do you already have data in this table by the time you `EXEC dbo.Match`? You have more fields than the 2 that are returned by the Stored Procedure and the calculated field. Where do `ValFromUser` and `ColumnName` come from? So far it looks like I have shown exactly how to do what you are asking for. If there is already data in that temp table before you EXEC the proc, that will be an issue. And why do you need the calculated value stored? Why not just add that calculation to the final SELECT?

Comment: @Simran Looking at your updates, I don't understand how #2 does not show exactly what you want to do?

Comment: I do have data already in this table and there will be data added in this table after execution of this procedure as well.ValFromUser is @MotherFN passed as argument and columnName needs to be added as 'MotherName' .I have got to deal with this calculated value further so I need it essentially.

Comment: Please check the update now. I am pretty sure it holds all the details now.

Comment: @Simran Yes, I see the update. And the situation is exactly the same as it was before even the first update. All 3 of the options I listed would work just fine. And if you really, really need the calculated field stored in the table (which I still doubt is necessary), then options 2 and 3 are _exactly_ what you need. The only thing your latest update adds are the `ValFromUser` and `ColumnName` fields, but that doesn't change the concept for either Options 2 or 3.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in general terms there is no value on creating complex logics if you just need to do simple stuffs. In the scenario that you described I would tend to think the best approach would be the use of phisical table that can be accessed any time by either the dbo.Match and dbo.MatchMotherFirstName procedures. If you don't want to leave it in the database after logic execution, use the CREATE/DROP sentences to CREATE/DROP the table as per your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 Easy enough options.  One has a decent sized performance hit, One requires a config update on the server and One requires a change to the match stored procedure.

**Option 1**
In the MatchMotherFirstName procedure declare a table for the Match results.

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpMatchResults (Col1 , Col2....)
Insert into #tmpMatchResults
EXEC [dbo].[MATCH]
```

This has a performance hit, but it works without any changes to the Match proc code or server config.  If you only expect very few lines, this will work just fine

**Option 2**
Use OpenRowSet or OpenQuery

```
Select * FROM OPENROWSET(connection,'Exec database.dbo.MATCH')
```

This requires a config change to allow data access

**Option 3**
Update the MATCH Stored Procedure to push the results to a temp table

```
CREATE Procedure [dbo].[MATCH]
--SOME CODE
select RowId, PercentMatch from #tmpMatches
```

Be sure NOT to drop the temp table at the end of the proc

Then In your MatchMotherFirstName procedure, while the session is active, you can call the proc

```
EXEC dbo.MATCH @param
```

and the result set with

```
SELECT * FROM #tmpMatches
```

Some people would argue that you should clean up (drop table) the temp table at the end of the MATCH proc call.  You can include a parameter in the MATCH proc to persist results or do table cleanup.

Comment: I think I created some serious misunderstanding in what I was trying to ask by not showing Temporary table. Updated the question with it. Could you please have a look ?