# How to extract list of ids and set to output parameter in stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I read through this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29174107/sharing-data-between-stored-procedures), but O think there must very simple way,which i am not able to figure out how i can get objects or array list of strings or integers.

Say I have table Employee and it has id. I just need list of ids and store it in output parameters like

```sql
select id from Employee //This gives a list of integers
```

I currently have a working code

```
IF OBJECT_ID('temp16', 'P') IS NOT NULL
    DROP PROCEDURE temp16
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE temp16(  @res int output)
AS
begin
SELECT @res=count(*) from [dbo].[Employee]
end;

//Calling this..

declare @res int;
exec dbo.temp16 @res=@res output ;
select @res
```

Instead of count(*),i need all list of ids. so something like this is needed,I am PSUEDOCODE

```
IF OBJECT_ID('temp16', 'P') IS NOT NULL
    DROP PROCEDURE temp16
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE temp16(  @res List<Id> output)
AS
begin
SELECT @res= id from [dbo].[Employee]
end;

declare @res list<int>;
exec dbo.temp16 @res=@res output ;
select @res
```

Comment: Commonly, one would return the list as a result set using a SELECT query like `SELECT id from [dbo].[Employee];` and the app code would transform the results onto the objects of choice.

Comment: Yes,i understand..But my idea is to get that list and use in it another stored procedure as inputimmediatly.Basically,its a little complex code taking many joins and network calls.so we decided to completely put it as storedprocedure to comeover the network calls which i slowing down performance

Comment: You could use `FOR JSON` and then parse it in your next stored proc

Comment: The "simple ways" were addressed in the link and in Erland's discussion. You resist and discard the many suggestions without reason - why? Seems like your team will need some guidance finding a solution and implementing it. The reference to "network calls" leads me to think that you have a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).